# Circe - Use default fields in case class when decoding/encoding json

Tags: scala, akka-http, circe

Lets say I have this case class:

`case class Foo(bar: String, baz: Boolean = false)`

which is used in when decoding/encoding API requests/responses using [akka-http-json](https://github.com/hseeberger/akka-http-json)

in an example similar to [this](https://github.com/hseeberger/akka-http-json/blob/master/akka-http-circe/src/test/scala/de/heikoseeberger/akkahttpcirce/ExampleApp.scala):

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives
import akka.stream.{ ActorMaterializer, Materializer }
import scala.io.StdIn

object ExampleApp {

  private final case class Foo(bar: String, baz: Boolean = false)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem()
    implicit val mat    = ActorMaterializer()

    Http().bindAndHandle(route, "127.0.0.1", 8000)

    StdIn.readLine("Hit ENTER to exit")
    system.terminate()
  }

  private def route(implicit mat: Materializer) = {
    import Directives._
    import FailFastCirceSupport._
    import io.circe.generic.auto._

    pathSingleSlash {
      post {
        entity(as[Foo]) { foo =>
          complete {
            foo
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine as long as the json message includes the `baz` field. However, I want to be able to send a json message `{bar: "something"}` and let the result use `Foo`'s default value for `baz`. Is there any configuration in `circe` or `akka-http-json` that could make this work?

Also, would be nice to ignore the `baz` field when encoding to json again, but this is not that important.

**Edit**:

I know I can do something like this:

```
implicit val fooEncoder: Encoder[Foo] = new Encoder[Foo] {
    final def apply(a: Foo): Json = Json.obj(
      ("id", Json.fromString(a.bar))
    )
  }

implicit val fooDecoder: Decoder[Foo] = new Decoder[Decoder] {
  final def apply(c: HCursor): Decoder.Result[Decoder] =
    for {
      bar <- c.downField("bar").as[String]
    } yield {
      Foo(bar)
    }
}
```

but was hoping for an easier-to-maintain solution, solving the general case of not requiring the default fields in the json message.

Comment: Would using a `Option[Boolean]` be a valid workaround? And setting it to `None` when not needed?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov it's a good suggestion, but in this case we use the case class also with [quill](http://getquill.io/). Since the default field should be `NOT NULL` in our database, it would be nice to keep it as a non-option in the case class.

Comment: @simen-andresen You should consider accepting the below solution

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this using the circe-generic-extras package.  It's a separate dependency you have to put in your build.  For sbt, that's:

```
libraryDependencies += "io.circe" %% "circe-generic-extras" % "0.8.0"
```

Then, in your route function, replace

```
import io.circe.generic.extras.Configuration
import io.circe.generic.auto._
```

with:

```
import io.circe.generic.extras.auto._
implicit val customConfig: Configuration = Configuration.default.withDefaults
```

The encoders this generates will always include the default fields.

For more info see the circe release notes at: https://github.com/circe/circe/releases/tag/v0.6.0-RC1

Comment: This didn't work for me. The Configuration class is not in `extras.auto` but only in `extras`. Also I was only able to use 0.14.3 and not 0.14.5 versions with scala 2.13